# pdftex driver of hyperref package doesn't work with utf-8 encoded .tex files

Tags: latex, pdflatex, hyperref

i use pdflatex to generate pdf files. my source files are all utf-8 encoded because of non-english characters. without `\usepackage{hyperref}` code, they can be compiled without any problem. but when i put `\usepackage{hyperref}` (even without any `\href{}{}` code) in the package list, an error would occur, saying

```
**************************************
! Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.  
\CJK@altchar ...fx \csname \reserved@a \endcsname   
                                                  \relax \CJKsymbol {\@tempc...  
l.1 \chapter{XXX}                    
?  
**************************************
```

where "XXX" represents non-english characters.

then i googled a lot, finding the cause is that hyperref uses pdftex drivers, which doesn't work with utf-8 encoded files. i checked this page: http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html , and failed to find any driver suitable for pdflatex.

i tried `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, but still couldn't get it to work.

so anyone could help me? thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried loading hyperref using `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}`, or, equivalently, specifying `\hypersetup{ unicode = true }` right after ? This should enable you to use unicode characters in bookmarks.

Comment: This solved it for me (utf8 names in PDF chapters using lualatex). Note that two recompilations might be needed (to update the table of contents).

Answer (score 2):

Try this, works for me. Instead of:

```
\usepackage[pdftex, unicode,
            pdfauthor={çç êÊ},
            pdftitle={T\'{o}picos Avançados ôô},
            pdfsubject={Trabalho 6},
            pdfkeywords={a1, a2},
            pdfproducer={Latex with hyperref},
            pdfcreator={pdflatex}]{hyperref}
```

I do:

```
\usepackage[pdftex, unicode,
            pdfproducer={Latex with hyperref},
            pdfcreator={pdflatex}]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={çç êÊ},
  pdftitle={T\'{o}picos Avançados ôô},
  pdfsubject={Trabalho 6},
  pdfkeywords={a1, a2},
}
```

I hope it works for you too.